# Derby dialect for hibernate

Tags: apache, hibernate, dialect

As per [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#configuring-dialects) there is no support mentioned for derby dialect for 4.2 hibernate.

Is Apache Derby not supported by Hibernate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are more dialects if you look at the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html). As of the time of the latest update to this answer, they are:

- `DerbyDialect` (deprecated, see [HHH-6073](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6073)),
- `DerbyTenFiveDialect`,
- `DerbyTenSixDialect`, and
- `DerbyTenSevenDialect`.

For versions of Derby after 10.7, the `DerbyTenSevenDialect` dialect would be the most appropriate, assuming no new Derby dialect classes are added.  (But if that happens, it is advisable to pick the "latest" dialect class that is less or equal to the Derby version you are using.)

Comment: ok ... but then derby is currently in version 10.10 and 10.9 both are wihc under active use but the dialects for them are missing

Comment: I'd use the closest version.

Comment: thats logical ... but what could be missing ? there is no doc on dialects specific to a database ... hope GAVIN reads this and give some more info